# What is the difference between services and profiles in a BLE GATT server

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm new to Bluetooth classic and Bluetooth Low Energy. After I watch the tutorial video on the dev site of android. I still don't understand what is a service in ble and what is the difference between service and profile. Can anyone helpe me?

Thanks.

Comment: Profile defines how to use the Attribute Protocol to discover, read, write and obtain indications. While services defines the characteristics and relationships to other services. To more pls refer this link [bluetooth.org Profile](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/BLE.aspx) and [BLE Service](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Profile define all communication functions to a BLE device, you can assume it is a higher level of abstraction, it has one or more service, which expose the sensor data on a GATT server. e.g Heart rate, temperature or Cycle speed. In simple Profile has Services, and Service has Characteristics, Characteristic descriptor.